# Image do not resize with ImageView

Tags: android, imageview

I have an ImageView.
I set it in xml as below:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/background"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

And set image as below:

```
ImageView background
background.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

But if the ImageView's parent layout narrow down, the IamgeView also narrow down.
And the image was resized.
I want to let it don't resize.
Is it can modify by setScaleType?
Or how to do it?

Comment: please provide some screenshots for more info

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try setting [adjustViewBounds](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:adjustViewBounds) parameter to true on the ImageView.

```
<ImageView
   android:id="@+id/background"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
   android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use `scaledBitmap` like this

```
Bitmap bMap =   Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(chosenBitmap, needed_width, needed_height, true);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bMap);
```